# Solve equation in prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Solve the equation in prime number $$p^3+q^3+1=p^2 q^2.$$

I have found the solutions $(2,3), (3,2)$ and need to prove that there are no other solutions. I think that there is an inequality $p^3+q^3+1\leq p^2 q^2$ for $p,q >2 $  but  how to prove it.

Comment: your inequality is not right when $p>q^2$, for then $p^3 > p^2 q^2$.

Answer (score 6):

If $p=q$ we get $2p^3+1=p^4$ so $p\mid 1$ which is impossible. So we can assume $p\ne q$.

Because of simmetry we can also assume that $p>q$.

Now we have $$p^2\mid q^3+1 = (q+1)(q^2-q+1)$$

**Case 1:** $p\not{\mid}\;q+1$, then $$p^2\mid q^2-q+1\implies p^2\leq q^2-q+1<q^2$$
so $p<q$, a contradiction.

**Case 2:** $p\mid q+1$ then $p\leq q+1$ so $p=q+1$ (remember that $p>q$, so $p\geq q+1$). So $p$ and $q$ are consecutive primes so one is even, so $q=2$ and $p=3$.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

**Case 1.** Let $p \mod 3=q \mod 3=1$. Then $p^3+q^3+1=3=0  \mod 3 \neq p^2 q^2=1 \mod 3$

**Case 2**  $p \mod 3=q \mod 3=2$. Then $p^3+q^3+1=2+2+1=2  \mod 3 \neq p^2 q^2=1 \mod 3$

**Сase 3.** $p \mod 3=1, q \mod 3=2$. Then $p^3+q^3+1=1+2+1=1  \mod 3 \neq p^2 q^2=1 \cdot 2 =2 \mod 3$

So, must be, say $p=0 \mod 3 \implies p=3$.  We get the equation $q^3+28=9 q^2 $ or $q^3-9 q^2+28=\left( q-2 \right)  \left( {q}^{2}-7\,q-14 \right) $ and $q=2.$ By symmetry another solution is $p=2, q=3.$

Comment: you have an important error, in Case 3, actually both $p^2, q^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3, $ therefore $p^2 q^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3, $