# How to find number of solutions and how to prove this integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If the number of pairs of prime numbers $(\alpha,\beta)$ that satisfy $$\alpha^3+\beta^3+1=\alpha^2\beta^2$$ is $m$ then prove that $$\binom{mk}{k}=\frac{m}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{m}}(m\sin x)^{mk}dx$$

My initial goal is to find $m.$ First consider the case $\alpha=\beta$ $$\implies 2\alpha^3+1=\alpha^4$$ Since increasing rate of $\alpha^4$ is more than $2\alpha^3+1$ so no solution exists.

No let $\beta>\alpha$ $$\implies \beta^3+(\alpha^3+1)=\alpha^2\beta^2$$
Now I'm stuck. How to find solutions to this equation$?$ Any idea is greatly appreciated. I understood how to find the value of $m$ but can anyone guide me in the process of integration$?$

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1692992p10835629). So $(p,q)=(2,3),(3,2)$, i.e., $m=2$.

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2991909/42969

Comment: Thanks...but what about the integration??

Comment: Also the integral is a duplicate - have a look (use residue theory).